# 3D audio visualizer in blender

Tags: audio

I would like to create an audio visualizer in 3 dimensions in Blender, like this :[image: waveform 01]

[image: waveform 02]

How can I do it?

Comment: Is this visualizing the wave form? or just how loud the track is?

Comment: It visualizes the amplitude and Frequencies by the time. [link](https://postimg.org/image/mzh3um7el/)

Comment: oh, so you mean like an EQ? When there is bass, the left half gets bigger, and when there is treble the right half gets bigger?

Comment: What have you got so far? What have you tried, and what didn't work? A simple google search [yielded a lot of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+audio+visualization)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This kind of animation are in 2 dimensions (I did it yet with few plugins) I would like to create a spectrogram in 3 dimensions (time, amplitude, frequency).

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, you could bake the amp or the eq to f-curves, the second picture you posted was from the wavetable window in serum, which is not a regular audio visualizer, it's a scanned wavetable viewer. Not really sure what you are asking here.